# How to capture the celery warning(s) from logs?

Tags: python, redis, celery, celery-task

I am using `celery` in conjunction with `fastapi` & the results are being logged in a file called `celery.log` via the command

```
celery worker --app=app.celery_worker.celery --loglevel=info --logfile=app/logs/celery.log
```

When the code is triggered, the logs are written in the `celery.log` file as follows:

```
[2022-05-20 11:38:35,148: INFO/MainProcess] Received task: kwept_calculation[bd80737a-92cd-4fea-8a68-c010d5ab3ed3]  
[2022-05-20 11:38:46,249: WARNING/ForkPoolWorker-7] System mit Neuinstallation(en) nicht betreibbar (z.B. wegen nicht deckbarer Wärmenachfrage)
[2022-05-20 11:38:53,401: WARNING/ForkPoolWorker-7] System ohne Neuinstallation(en) nicht betreibbar (z.B. wegen nicht deckbarer Wärmenachfrage)
[2022-05-20 11:38:53,402: ERROR/ForkPoolWorker-7] Task kwept_calculation[bd80737a-92cd-4fea-8a68-c010d5ab3ed3] raised unexpected: UnboundLocalError("local variable 'kpis_df' referenced before assignment")
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/celery/app/trace.py", line 412, in trace_task
    R = retval = fun(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/celery/app/trace.py", line 704, in __protected_call__
    return self.run(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/kwept/app/celery_worker.py", line 77, in calculation
    created_at_ts
  File "/kwept/app/services/planning_calc.py", line 571, in plan_calc
    kpis_df.reset_index(drop=False, inplace=True)
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'kpis_df' referenced before assignment
```

To get the info on the task, I do

```
from celery.result import AsyncResult
task_result = AsyncResult(task_id) # in the above case bd80737a-92cd-4fea-8a68-c010d5ab3ed3
task_info = task_result.info
```

When I do that, the error from the above `task_info` is captured

> local variable 'kpis_df' referenced before assignment

Is there a way to capture the warning messages? In the above example, the warnings are:

> System mit Neuinstallation(en) nicht betreibbar (z.B. wegen nicht
> deckbarer Wärmenachfrage)

and

> System ohne Neuinstallation(en) nicht betreibbar (z.B. wegen nicht
> deckbarer Wärmenachfrage)

Comment: The warnings are being written to the log file, how else do you want to capture them?

Comment: According the docs
BaseAsyncResult.info -> Alias to result().                                                                                     

When the task has been executed, this contains the return value.
If the task raised an exception, this will be the exception instance.

So, you can get return value or exception only

Answer (score 1):

If you want your warning messages as part of a custom field of the Celery task itself, you can try something like this and add it to the custom entry in meta-fields via [update_state() method](https://docs.celeryq.dev/en/stable/reference/celery.app.task.html#celery.app.task.Task.update_state):

```
@app.task(bind=True)
def task(self):
try:
    raise ValueError('Some error')
except Exception as ex:
    self.update_state(
        state=states.FAILURE,
        meta={
            'exc_type': type(ex).__name__,
            'exc_message': traceback.format_exc().split('\n')
            'custom': '...'
        })
    raise Ignore()
```

In your task definition you must update the code to not only log the warn message, but to put it into the meta fields.

When you need to check the task, you find your custom field here:

```
>>> print(task.info)
{'custom': '...'}
```

Comment: You are capturing exceptions here, not warnings...